# how can I get fullcalendar version 2.6

Tags: fullcalendar

Good afternoon! 
We need Full calendar version 2.6 and now only 2.2 is published. How can we  get it? Is it possible to send to us directly or when it is planned to be published?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the latest version (2.6.1) [here](http://fullcalendar.io/download/)